# properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"] returns zero

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, file-upload

I have created an event receiver on item add event. I am trying to get file size during upload. For this I have used **properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"].** This is working properly for the small sized files but for the larger files(300MB+) **properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"]** returns zero.
I have no clue why it is behaving like this. Any ideas regarding this?